# Process started via remote session on Azure Release Pipeline killed after timeout

Tags: c#, azure, azure-devops, devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

In this topic 2 machines are involved: the BuildMachine and the TargetMachine (I define them below).

I use Azure devops on a private instance.
In the release pipeline, I install a software on a TargetMachine.
To do so, the release Pipeline:

- Is executed by a self-hosted agent. (Agent.Version: 2.153.1) on the BuildMachin
- Uploads a powershell script on the TargetMachine
- Runs a remote powershell session on the TargetMachine via the following tasks:

[image: task config]

The powershell script:

- stops the targeted exe
- update the bin folder
- start again the exe
- exits **without waiting the ExitCode because the application is a server which MUST stay alive**.
  with the following code:

```
    Stop-Process -Name "TOTO" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    ......
    Start-Process -FilePath "C:\toto.exe" -WorkingDirectory "C:\" -WindowStyle Maximized
    Write-Output "Process is started"
    Exit 0
```

The release pipeline finish **successfully** and the powershell task takes :
35 seconds:
[image]

**BUT** after 1 minute 20 seconds the process is killed.
The process is a console application which is a TCP server, it should stay alive forever ( same issue if I add a winform app with a button to click).

The config of my ps task is the following (60 seconds is greater than the currend powershell execution time of 35 seconds):

```
    -SkipCACheck -IdleTimeout 60000 -OperationTimeout 60000 -OutputBufferingMode Block
```

[image: ps config]

Even when I multiply by 10 the timeout , the targetProcess is killed after 1'20":

```
    -SkipCACheck -IdleTimeout 600000 -OperationTimeout 600000 -OutputBufferingMode Block
```

and even when i reduce the parameters of pssession to :
[image: ps session params]

In a local command prompt of the TargetMachine, open as an Admin, i run the same script without issue, and the process is not killed:

```
    powershell ./release_TAS.ps1
```

The script takes 10 seconds to execute.

=> is there a setting somewhere to indicate that child process created by ps can continue to live alone indefinitely ?
How can I start a process via azure release pipeline, and let it execute without waiting for exit code.

Regards

Comment: Could you please share us some more details?
1. Are you using the Microsoft-Hosted agent or the self-Hosted agent?
2. Could you please try to run the Powershell script on the target VM manually and check if this issue still happen?
3. If it is possible, please try to install a self-agent in your vm and use the new self-agent to run the pipeline again to check if it has the same issue.

Comment: I updated my question with the detail you ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is not resolve but I think I found the responsible wsmprovhost.exe:

My Tas.exe and BasicGui.exe are killed in same time as (some milisecond after) another process that I do not touch: 'wsmprovhost.exe'
[image: wsmprovhost.exe]

> wsmprovhost.exe is a Windows Remote Powershell session,when you enter a remote session ,you create on the server a process called wsmprovhost.exe.When you simply start a process in this remote session,the  new process will be a child of wsmprovhost.exe.

> When a local computer connects to a remote computer, WS-Management establishes a connection and uses a plug-in for PowerShell to start the PowerShell host process (Wsmprovhost.exe) on the remote computer.

On this page I found an interesting paragraph:
[Powershell params](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-7.1)

> To run a command in a disconnected session, use the **InDisconnectedSession** parameter. To run a command in a background job, use the **AsJob** parameter.

I reproduce the issue from my local machine with a powershell scipts which start the target server process on the remote machine, and the target remote process is killed once my local script stops:

```
$username = 'xxx'
$password = 'yyy'
$secpw = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$cred  = New-Object Management.Automation.PSCredential ($username, $secpw)
Invoke-Command -FilePath C:\Xoru\DEV\Install\release_TAS.ps1 -ComputerName SCHTROUPHFER -Credential $cred
```

However the process of my server is not killed if I run the command with the  parameter '-InDisconnectedSession':

```
Invoke-Command -FilePath C:\Xoru\DEV\Install\release_TAS.ps1 -ComputerName SCHTROUPHFER -Credential $cred -InDisconnectedSession
```

The issue is that the remote power shell task on azzure is not using the Invoke-Command, but the New-PsSession which takes as optional param a dummy New-PSSessionOption object **which do not** accept -InDisconnectedSession param , haha!.... .a!@#$%^&*()

[image: option of pw task]

...zzzoo ze zoluzion..... consist in not using remote powershell script, but local powershell script on zeee build machine and ask it to execute remotely in a disconnected state (haha) the script on the target machine:

[image: pipeline config]

Above you see:

- a task to push on the target machine ze zip
- a task to copy on the build machine a powershell script to be executed on the target machine
- a task to execute a powershell script on the build machine (where the agent is executed) to execute remotely the content of the powershell script (InstallScript)

After this, the target process : Tas.exe remains alive after the release pipeline is finished. GREAT !

Comment: in fact even with this workaround, the process is killed. only it is delayed to 2 hours later.... this is so dummy stuff!

Answer (score 0):

It seems your Powershell script is taking a lot of time. You will have to increase [IdleTimeout and OperationTimeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/new-pssessionoption?view=powershell-7.1) values to **what is actually required**.

Currently, your `IdleTimeout` is 1 minutes (60000 ms) and `OperationTimeout` is 30 seconds (30000 ms).

Comment: I updated my question with your comment , increased 30 sec to 60 sec => same issue

Comment: How much does your script take in your local machine?

Comment: Do you mean the console application is run by your PS script? Fire and forget? And it is killed?

Comment: script : 10 seconds
yes : the ps script launches the app , forget it , and after 1.20 minutes killed. this is not an app issue as i tried with different exe.
topic is updated in the body with this info.
can 't you reproduce ?

Comment: Even when I multiply by 10 the timeout , the targetProcess is killed after 1'20"

Comment: So, this is for powershell session. There is something wrong with your console application, have you added logs there? Pls check the logs for errors.

Comment: I thought the same thing that there might be a bug in console making it to crash. I resolved the ambiguity in adding a winform application with a button to clikc to kill. result : powershell script launches the 2 exe, i see them on taskmanager, and bothe exe disapeer after 1 minute each time i release. ==>there is no problem in the console application

Answer (score 0):

Some months after I come back to add more insight to this highly viewed topic.
My final solution is to migrate the process (console app) to a windows service.
I started initially a home made server as console app, and with some effort converted it as Service, and this issue is not happening anymore.

If you have same issue in case you want a persist .exe life turn into windows service, this will also benefit from the fact that it will be auto restarted at machine reboot , which is often the case for Windows updates on Servers.

If you are not owner of the code of the target .exe i think it is not possible. or maybe look at task scheduler to find a workaround as .exe behavior do not needs to be changed when invoked by task scheduler (but you will still have issues at machine reboot)